# ASP.net beginner really confused about StaticObjects and how to declare it

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, application-start, application-state

I'm a beginner in ASP.net, i did some research about Application state. I know about declaring new application state inside the `Application_start` event.

But when i looked inside MSDN library (which is not helpful at all
unfortunately). I found this paragraph:

> Alternatively, you can add objects to the StaticObjects collection via an 
>   declaration in your Web application's Global.asax file. Application
>   state defined in this way can then be accessed from code anywhere in
>   your application. The following example shows an object declaration
>   for an application state value:
>
> ```
> <object runat="server" scope="application" ID="MyInfo" 
>     PROGID="MSWC.MYINFO">
> </object>
> ```
>
> You can add objects to the StaticObjects collection only in the
>   Global.asax file. The collection throws a NotSupportedException if you
>   attempt to add objects directly through code.
>
> You can access members of objects stored in application state without
>   having to reference the Application collection. The following code
>   example shows how to reference a member of an object defined in the
>   StaticObjects collection of application state. Notice that the label
>   identifier defined in Global.asax is used as the variable name.

I really have no idea how to `add objects to the StaticObjects collection via an <object runat="server"> declaration in your Web application's Global.asax file.`

1. How to add `<object>` tag?
2. What is `<object>` tag in the first place?
3. What is `StaticObject` collection?
4. How to add "tags" inside a `Global.asax` (C# code) ?

I know my questions are very primitive but i really want to understand things well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN is not always right, especially some of the example code is often weird.

The XML code can be put into `web.config` file, whereas `global.asax.cs` contains handlers for different app lifecycle events, so you can achieve similar results programatically for example in `Application_Start` event handler.

Comment: So i should put those lines of code inside `web.config` file? Inside `<system.web>` tags ?

Comment: Yes, you can put the <staticObject> collection containing your <object> tags into <system.web> collection, then you can access it programatically from anywhere in your application, event Application_Start, like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx